# Need help with expressing this logarithm

Tags: logarithms

Express $log_3(a^2 + \sqrt{b})$ in terms of m and k where
 $m = log_{3}a$

$k = log_{3}b$

Given this information I made
$a = 3^m$

$b = 3^k$

Therefore
= $log_{3} ((3^m)^2 + (3^k))^{\frac{1}{2}}$

= $log_{3} (3^{2m} + 3^{\frac{k}{2}})$

I don't know if I'm done or there is still more things I can simplify. Can anyone help please, thanks

Comment: Is 3 in base ???

Comment: Yes it's in the base

Comment: Any ideas you have on simplification

Comment: Maybe the log 3 and the two 3's cancel out leaving only the exponents

Comment: So its 2m + k/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no expansion for $\log(a+b)$, hence, you could stop there. If you need to get an approximation(sometimes in computer science), you could use $\log(a+b)=\log a+\log(1+b/a)$, then you have following:
$$2m+\log_3(1+3^{k/2-2m}).$$

Comment: Makes sense, but doesn't express in terms of k and m mean that k and m should be the only terms in an expression? Maybe I'm just wrong

Comment: @Questionasker: that's what they are here !

Comment: @Questionasker: $\log$ is just an operator, not a variable etc, hence, it's enough to express it using $\log$. If you have more conditions on $k$ and $m$, then maybe you could simplify the expression without $\log$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, $\log_3(9^m+\sqrt3^k)$, but this makes little difference.

You can't decompose a sum inside a logarithm.